# Reason for reduction in reputation

Tags: support, reputation

At the beginning of the day my reputation was 757, but by the end it had reduced to 722, and I can't figure out the reason. I haven't been downvoted, so it'd be nice to know the reason for the sudden rep loss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have checked your reputation history and there is nothing there, then this is most likely due to the people at SO doing some corrections. In other words there was probably an error in calculation (or something else) and they've corrected it.

Comment: in other words, a reputation recalc.

Comment: This is correct; there was a recalc on this account today.

Answer (score 1):

Some people could have changed the answer they accepted from your answer to another answer.  That would drop your rep by 15, but there would not be an indication in your history.  (Same thing for vote reversal)